# Maximize this equation E[a1]-E[a2]+E[a3]-E[a4]

Tags: c++, recursion, dynamic, divide-and-conquer

Can anyone please help me how todo this problem

We have to maximize the value of:
E[a1]- E[a2]+ E[a3]- E[a4]
where E is an array
constraints:
1<=E<=100 (size)

N>=4

a1>a2>a3>a4 (index)

Input format

N (no. of integers in array)

N value separated by spaces

Output

single integer(max value)

Test case:
I/P

6

3 9 10 1 30 40

O/P

46 (40-1+10-3)(index: 5>3>2>0)

Comment: What have you tried so far, and where are you having problems with it?

Comment: 40-1+10-3 is 46, not 47.

Comment: I have used divide and conquer algorithm but it won't work I got stuck

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
int n;

cin>>n;

vector<int> v(n);

for(int i=0; i<n; i++) 

cin>>v[i];

vector<int> a1(n);

vector<int> a2(n);

vector<int> a3(n);

vector<int> a4(n);

int max4 = (-1)*v[0];

for(int i=0; i<n; i++)
{
    max4 = max(max4, (-1)*v[i]);
    a4[i] = max4;
}

int max3 = v[1]-v[0];
for(int i=1; i<n; i++)
{
    max3 = max(max3, v[i]+a4[i-1]);
    a3[i] = max3;
}

int max2 = (-1)*v[2]+v[1]-v[0];
for(int i=2; i<n; i++)
{
    max2 = max(max2, (-1)*v[i]+a3[i-1]);
    a2[i] = max2;
}

int max1 = v[3]-v[2]+v[1]-v[0];
for(int i=3; i<n; i++)
{
    max1 = max(max1, v[i]+a2[i-1]);
    a1[i] = max1;
}
cout<<a1[n-1]<<endl;
return 0;    
}
```

Since nobody cared to answer so I did on my own using dp

Comment: Isn't this similar to the DP strategy I had outlined? Also, if you change all but the last loop to min() operations, I think you can avoid all of the multiplications by (-1). Not a big change, but can make the code shorter/cleaner and easier to generalize

Answer (score 0):

It's best to break this problem down, and start with smaller cases.
How would we maximize `E[i]- E[j]` for `i > j`? We could track, for every index i, the minimum value in `E` before `i` in an array `one_diff` where `one_diff[i] = min(E[0], E[1], ... E[i-1])`. Then, the max of `E[i]- E[j]` for a given i is just `E[i] - one_diff[i]`.

For three terms, the max of `E[i]- E[j] + E[k]` for a fixed `i` is `E[i] - min(E[j] - E[k]) over all j < i and k < j`. The subproblem here is actually the same as the last problem, except we now want the min of `E[j]- E[k]` for a given j, so change every max to a min.

For four terms, the max of `E[i]- E[j] + E[k] - E[l]` requires the min of `E[j]- E[k] + E[l]` for a fixed `j`, and variable `k, l` with `l < k < j`, so the progression is the same as going from two to three terms.

In dynamic programming over `n` variables, you should first try writing the answer in terms of a subproblem with `n-1` variables, then solve that subproblem.

Comment: thanks but I wasn’t able to implement divide and conquer algorithm at last i used dp and it worked